# How to get the position of the word when found in a text in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

The table has word and sentences. If the word is found, how to get the position of it?
Below temp.word has information security and information both. For the id = 100, I am expecting to see the information when it appeared the second time (For more information,) as we have Information security in temp.word. So, we need to skip Information security. The code below picks the information which appears first.

```
Create table temp(
  id       NUMBER,
  word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  Sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
);

insert into temp 
select 100,'Information Security','Information security, sometimes shortened to infosec. For more information, visit https://infosec.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 200,'Information','Information-security information.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 300,'Info','https://infosec.com Information Security' FROM DUAL;

select word,sentence, regexp_instr(sentence,word,1, 1, 0,'i') as token
from temp
where instr(UPPER(sentence), UPPER('information')) > 0
and regexp_like(sentence,'information','i')
```

Answer (score 1):

For finding second appearance, you can use `regexp_substr`.

Syntax for it goes like this:

> REGEXP_INSTR( string, pattern [, start_position [, nth_appearance [,
>   return_option [, match_parameter [, sub_expression ] ] ] ] ] )

In your case use 2 as the `nth_appearance` as following

```
regexp_instr(sentence,word,1, 2, 0,'i') as token
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9b0e3129dacea2cb904bdd5586ca56de)

Cheers!!